# How to bind data in checkbox list in Gridview with same datatable?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to give checkbox list in `Gridview`. How can I bind data to checkbox list from same data table?

Comment: maybe sharing some code?

Answer (score 1):

What i understood that i am showing let me know you are asking for the same or not

This is the design portion

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="gridview"
                                           >
                                            <Columns>
                                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="name" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name")%>'>></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Roll No">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                                <asp:Label ID="rollno" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Roll_No")%>'>></asp:Label>
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
                                            <ItemTemplate>
                                               <asp:CheckBox runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Gender")%>' />
                                            </ItemTemplate>
                                        </asp:TemplateField>
                                                </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Here I have made a temoporary data table you can make data table through database also

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (!IsPostBack) {
            check_box();
        }
    }

    public void check_box() {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name");
        dt.Columns.Add("Roll_NO");
        dt.Columns.Add("Gender");
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[0][0]="Prateek Ghosh";
        dt.Rows[0][1] = 123;
        dt.Rows[0][2] = "Male";
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[1][0] = "Rahul";
        dt.Rows[1][1] = 1234;
        dt.Rows[1][2] = "Male";
        dt.Rows.Add();
        dt.Rows[2][0] = "Neha";
        dt.Rows[2][1] = 12345;
        dt.Rows[2][2] = "Female";

        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

[image: Final Result]